# how can an array of pointers to char hold strings instead of addresses?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Can anyone explain how the following program works? here `name[]` is an array of pointers to char then how can name contain values instead of addresses and how come the values stored are strings rather than character?

```
#include <stdio.h>   
const int MAX = 4;   
int main () {     
    char *names[] = {      
        "Zara Ali",       
        "Hina Ali",       
        "Nuha     Ali",       
        "Sara Ali",    };        
    int i = 0;     
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {       
        printf("Value of names[%d] = %s\n", i, names[i] );  
    }        
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a simpler example:

```
char *s = "abcd";
printf( "s = %p\n", (void *)s );  // 1) address
printf( "s = %c\n", *s );         // 2) char
printf( "s = %s\n", s );          // 3) string
```

Here `s` is a pointer to char (similar to your `names[i]`, also a pointer to char). Actually `s` can be interpreted as 1) an address, 2) a normal pointer to char, or 3) a string.

First `s` is a pointer, so `s` holds address of something it points to. You can check what address it is by the first `printf` using `%p` control string.

Second, `s` is a pointer to char, so you can deference it as normal, using printf `%c` which would print the first char.

Third, `s` is a pointer to char which is one way to declare C `string` (another way is using array). C string is a consecutive array of characters ending with `\0` as delimiter. When using printf `%s` you are printing it as a string.

Comment: for using s as character we write "printf( "s = %c\n", *s );" and for string we write "printf( "s = %s\n", s ); " .Why for printing a character we use *s and for string only s??

Comment: you are not newbie (ie you can vote), consider vote up the accepted  answer

Answer (score 2):

A string literal like `"Zara Ali"` evaluates to the address of its first character.

The string literal is generally stored in read-only data segment.

So essentially **your array contains addresses**.

You can also write

```
char *str="Zara Ali";
//The value of a string literal is the address of its first character.
```

Comment: can u plzz explain in little more detail what do u actually mean by the line "The value of a string literal is the address of its first character.
"  ?

Comment: @sameersoin Consider a string `"Ali"`. It would be stored in memory and would take up 4 bytes of memory in the read only segment (4th byte for storing `'\0'`). When you write `"Ali"` all it means is the address of the 1st byte. So `char *ptr="Ali";` would assign the address of the 1st byte to `ptr`.